# time.sleep() in Blender (Cycles) script

Tags: python, blender

I am trying to change the color of a Cube with a delay between the two colors. It's seem not possible with

```
time.sleep(5)
```

When I run the script, it waits 5s and displays just the second color and the first is never used.

```
import bpy
import time
mat = bpy.data.materials.new("RED")
mat.diffuse_color = (0.8,0,0)
mesh = bpy.context.object.data
mesh.materials.append(mat)

time.sleep(5)

mat = bpy.data.materials.new("GREEN")
mat.diffuse_color = (0,0.8,0)
mesh = bpy.context.object.data
mesh.materials.clear()
mesh.materials.append(mat)
```

Certes il manquait "object", mais c n'est pas l'origine du phénomène, j'ai essayé les deux changments de couleurs séparément pas de problème, mais lors que je les assemble et les sépare par time.sleep(5) seul de vert est affiché ! Merci de ta réponse

Comment: You might want to show the relevant part of the code that you're running, this will help us help you.

Pourrais tu inclure la partie du code en question? Ça nous aiderait à t'aider!

Comment: Merci, je compléte ma question !

Comment: est-ce que c'est normal que la premiere fois: `mesh = bpy.context.data` et la deuxieme fois `mesh = bpy.context.object.data` ? J'aurais tendance a croire que ca pourrait etre la partie coupable de ton erreur. Je n'ai pas regardé la doc de `bpy` par contre

Comment: J'ai enfin touvé. C'est une question de rafraichissement de l'affichage de Blender, il suffit d'ajouter avant le time.sleep : bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)

Answer (score 1):

```
bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
```

Comment: super, je te suggere de traduire ta reponse en anglais, histoire de pouvoir aider + de monde!